# Display of plotted point labels not appearing properly on X Range Chart for the first date of month - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, highcharts

I am currently working out on a x range chart to display timeline of activities. I am facing issue with the popup used for the data information display while placing my cursor over the bars.

For every first date of any particular month, I am not getting the accurate information needed.

Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
       type: 'xrange',
        styledMode: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts X-range'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        categories: ['Proto', 'Dev', 'Test'],
        reversed: true
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project:',

        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 2),
            y: 0,
            partialFill: 0.25
        },  {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 2, 1),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 3, 19),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
            y: 2
        }],
          dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
       }]

      });
```

I expect the output to be in the format of below:

Wednesday, Jan 1, 2014 - Monday, Jun 2, 2014
Project: Proto

But the actual output is:

January 2014 - June 2014
Project: Proto

I will be very grateful if someone can help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize tooltip content using `tooltip.formatter` callback function and format dates as you like using `Highcharts.dateFormat()` method. Check the code and demo posted below.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    styledMode: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Proto', 'Dev', 'Test'],
    reversed: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var point = this,
        series = point.series,
        color = point.color || series.chart.options.colors[point.colorIndex],
        firstDate = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', point.x),
        secondDate = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', point.x2),
        header = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + firstDate + ' - ' + secondDate + '</span><br/>',
        content = '<span style="color:' + color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + series.name + ': <b>' + point.yCategory + '</b><br/>';

      return header + content;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Project',
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 2),
      y: 0,
      partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 2, 1),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 3, 19),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
      y: 2
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }]

});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wbscy6q/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats